# Error: Module not found Docker Node Container

Tags: node.js, docker, module, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to deploy my node application on docker container.
here is my docker file

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
ENV NODE_ENV=development
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

here is the module not found error
[image: here is the module not found error]

here is my project directory
[image: here is my project directory]

here is my code location in linux
[image: code linux loctaion]

Comment: What produces the PNG files you show?  Can you edit the question to include the actual error message as text, and not an image?  How are you launching the container?  Does the application work outside of Docker?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copy your application source after doing the NPM install.

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
COPY . /usr/src/app
ENV NODE_ENV=development
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```